# php different versions with errors

Tags: php, versions

i wrote a small program to help me study, it works fine on the localhost, but when i upload it i get an error message that has me stumped

the line i get the error with is below

```
<?php echo "Num #  : " . ($_SESSION['monster']->getQuestionNumber()[$q]) ."&nbspof&nbsp". $_SESSION['monster'] -> getTotalQuestions() . "<BR>";?>
```

on the local host i have PHP Version 5.4.4-14+deb7u5

on the remote server i have PHP Version 5.2.6

the error i get is

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/user/htdocs/quizzme.php on line 57
```

any ideas

Comment: Yes; your remote php version doesn't support that syntax.

Comment: php < 5.4 do not support array dereferencing

Comment: It's called array dereferencing, and was introduced in PHP 5.4

Comment: yes, array dereferencing is not availabe in php < 5.4

Comment: I'm not sure why nobody has mentioned this yet, but this is called array dereferencing and was introduced in PHP 5.4. See [Example #7.](http://us3.php.net/language.types.array.php)

Comment: @Pekka웃 c.c You sure nobody has mentioned it yet?

Comment: @Daedalus pretty sure. Maybe we should mention it again just to make sure :)

Comment: @Pekka웃 There's something about dereferencing in one of the answers now. Perhaps that'll help.

Comment: Well despite who mentioned it first, lol, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array dereferencing is not supported on the earlier version of PHP.  You need to do something like this:

```
<?php 
    $temp = $_SESSION['monster']->getQuestionNumber();
    echo "Num #  : " . $temp[$q] ."&nbspof&nbsp". $_SESSION['monster'] -> getTotalQuestions() . "<BR>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a million, really appreciate your swift answer, works a treat.